# How can I set Content-MD5 header in Minio SDK for uploading to IBM Cloud Object Storage?

Tags: go, ibm-cloud, minio

I am trying to set the Content-MD5 header when I use Minio Golang SDK to upload a file to S3. I can successfully upload files to AWS without setting Content-MD5, but uploading to IBM Cloud Object Storage fails with the following error:

```
ERR: Object write failed, reason: Missing required header for this request: Content-MD5
```

According to the Minio SDK,
https://docs.minio.io/docs/golang-client-api-reference#FPutObject
I use the UserMetadata field in minio.PutObjectOptions to set Content-MD5, but IBM Cloud Object Storage keeps complaining missing MD5, am I doing something wrong in the following code?

```golang
func (cloudIO *CloudIO) FWrite(name string) (n int, err error) {
    f, err := os.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    h := md5.New()
    if _, err := io.Copy(h, f); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    bytesWritten, err := cloudIO.client.FPutObject(cloudIO.bucket, cloudIO.address,
        name,
        minio.PutObjectOptions{UserMetadata: map[string]string{"Content-MD5": hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))}})
    return int(bytesWritten), err
}
```

Comment: Looking at the sources, it looks to me this MD5 should be added automatically. Providing it as a custom header like you did, it will not make it to the final outgoing request, but the key will be prefixed by `"X-Amz-Meta-"` (as can be seen in [api-put-object.go / Header() method](https://github.com/minio/minio-go/blob/master/api-put-object.go#L91)). So to sum it, it's possible this is a bug, you should report it.

Comment: @icza Thanks. I saw exactly the same thing in the go file you mentioned. I am trying to capture the packet to verify if Content-MD5 is missing in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pacalj If you look at AWS documentation for `PutObject` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html . `Content-MD5` is not a required field. Meaning if it is not set by the client, the server should not error out, as you have already seen with AWS S3. As far as `minio-go` sdk is concerned, `content-MD5` cannot be set via `PutObjectOptions` as explained in https://docs.minio.io/docs/golang-client-api-reference#FPutObject

Minio-go sets `X-Amz-Content-Sha256` in the case of `http` connection and `Content-Md5` in the case of `https` connections. Minio-go's `FPutObject` and `PutObject` api abstracts both `multi-part put` and `single part put` into these APIs. In the case of `multi-part` PUT, each part will set either `X-Amz-Content-Sha256` or `Content-Md5` depending on the type of connection. Since the call is abstracted, it is not possible for a user to set `Content-Md5`.

I believe `IBM Cloud Object Storage` has a bug as it should not error out, even if `Content-Md5` is not set.

Comment: thanks for the great answer. I figured out the same conclusion as Content-Md5 cannot be set by a user, it will be bypassed and not added to the header, hence causing the error. I modified Minio-go sdk to add compatibility for IBM COS and now it solves the problem. But I agree that it could be a bug in the IBM side.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use minio [`Core`](https://github.com/minio/minio-go/blob/b2dc0664477393c30d39e3dc63ca4bbffead7749/core.go#L36) instead of `Client` to set the MD5 and SHA256 headers. As the [documentation says](https://github.com/minio/minio-go/blob/b2dc0664477393c30d39e3dc63ca4bbffead7749/core.go#L36) about `Core`:

> NewCore - Returns new initialized a Core client, this CoreClient
> should be only used under special conditions such as need to access
> lower primitives and being able to use them to write your own
> wrappers.

It has a [`PutObject` method](https://github.com/minio/minio-go/blob/b2dc0664477393c30d39e3dc63ca4bbffead7749/core.go#L73) that has the `md5Base64` and `sha256Hex` arguments.